# How to launch app by scanning NDEF NFC tag?

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I am trying to launch my app by scanning an NFC tag. I have two tags to test with,

1. one (lets call this "tag A") with one URI data type "http://panasonic.net" and
2. the other (lets call this "tag B") with two data types -- a URI (with TNF: TNF_WELL_KNOWN and RTD: RTD_URI) "urn:nfc:testing.com/ecm/ecap" and a URN (TNF: TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE) "urn:nfc:ext:testing.com:ecm".

Note: My main goal is to get tag B to work. Tag A is my test tag and it does not need to work with this app.

In my manifest, I give the permissions for NFC, and I have added the XML for the tech-discovered list in the manifest.

In the intent-filter tag, I have the following:

```
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

<strike>Without `TECH_DISCOVERED`, tag A is shown in the list of apps to launch automatically but tag B is not shown. With `TECH_DISCOVERED`, both tags are shown on the list.</strike>
Correction: Without `TECH_DISCOVERED`, for tag A and tag B, the app does not show up in the auto-launch list. But without `TECH_DISCOVERED` and `<data android:scheme="http" android:host="panasonic.net"/>`, tag A does get the app to show up in the auto-launch list. For tag A this is correct behavior because Chrome takes over and launches automatically when `<data ... android:host="panasonic.net"/>` is not there.

Next, I have specified some data tags in the intent-filter:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="panasonic.net"/>
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="fake.com"/>
```

When scanning tag A, it gets the app to show up on the list. When scanning tag B, the app is not shown in the list. This is correct behavior.

Then I add a data tag to the intent-filter for tag B:

```
<data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
      android:host="ext"
      android:pathPrefix="/com.informationmediary:ecm" />
```

This is where I start having trouble. I scan tag A and tag B, and the app does not show up in the auto-launch list for both. When I remove the HTTP data tags leaving only the "vnd.android.nfc" one and scan tag B again the app still does not show up.

I also tried the following variations to no avail:

EDIT: at this point I have removed the following hoping to get tag B to work only:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="panasonic.net"/>
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="fake.com"/>
```

1.

```
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/com.informationmediary:ecm" />
```

2.

```
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/informationmediary.com:ecm" />
```

3.

```
    <data android:scheme="urn:nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/com.informationmediary:ecm" />
```

4.

```
    <data android:scheme="urn:nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/informationmediary.com:ecm" />
```

5.

```
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="informationmediary.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/ecm/ecap"/>
```

6.

```
    <data android:scheme="urn:nfc"
          android:host="informationmediary.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/ecm/ecap"/>
```

I have tried all combinations of two of the top four with the bottom two:
1&5, 1&6, 2&5, 2&6, 3&5, 3&6, 4&5 and 4&6

I doubted scheme="urn:nfc" but tried it anyways, "grasping at straws" by this time.

Tag B is the one I need to work, tag A is a test one I have.

I have read the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#ext-type
And https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#mime and several other posts on forums that basically say the same thing as in the developer.android sights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adding the intent filter for Tag B results in Tag A no longer being picked up

When you add the data element

```
<data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
      android:host="ext"
      android:pathPrefix="/com.informationmediary:ecm" />
```

to your existing intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="panasonic.net" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="fake.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Android will merge all data elements into a single one. Consequently, your intent filter of the form

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="panasonic.net" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="fake.com" />
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/informationmediary.com:ecm" />
</intent-filter>
```

means that Android will try to match the URL on the tag like this:

```
(scheme == "http" OR scheme == "vnd.android.nfc") AND
(host == "panasonic.net" OR host == "fake.com" OR host == "ext") AND
(path startsWith "/informationmediary.com:ecm")
```

Therefore, the android:pathPrefix attribute must match th URL even if it is not explicitly specified on the other data elements.

You can easily get rid of that issue by specifying two separate intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="panasonic.net" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="fake.com" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/informationmediary.com:ecm" />
</intent-filter>
```

#### Tag B never matches the intent filter

Only the first record on a tag is matched against intent filters. Hence, in order to match the External Type record, you need to make it the first record on the tag. Then, if your External Type record contains the URI "urn:nfc:ext:informationmediary.com:ecm" it will match the above intent filter. Note that the record actually must contain only the part "informationmediary.com:ecm" since the prefix is implicit.

If you can't change the content of tag B though, you would need to match the URI record on that tag with the intent filter. Unfortunately, your URI on tag B is not easily usable with Android. The problem is that Android can only match host and path for URLs of the form "scheme://host/path" (note the slashes!). Since you use a URN instead, that does not have a host or path component. In this case, you could only try to match the scheme (i.e. "urn") on its own:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="urn" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can't differentiate between the remaining components of the URN though (i.e. there is no such differentiation as provided by host or path components).

Comment: ah i see, but than wouldn't the intent filter with android:host="informationmediary.com" android:pathPrefix="/ecm/ecap" match? and only that one since it is the first URI on the tag, it is the well known URI. will take me a bit to flip the well known type and the external type on the tag itself, i will try that when the hardware is fixed.

Comment: @user1 No, unfortunately, your URI on tag B is not easily usable with Android. The problem is that Android can only match host and path for URLs of the form scheme://host/path (note the slashes!), which your URN in the URI record does not have. You could try to match the scheme only (i.e. android:scheme="urn") without any host and path component though.

Comment: the external URN must be last I cannot move it up before the Well Known Type, so if I am following you correctly I must use the Well Known Type URI for the intent-filter, but I am unable to get that one working as well. I have tried the intent filter configurations in your last code block and tag A worked as you sayd it would but I am still having issues with tag B using the well known type 
                data scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
                host="informationmediary.com"
                pathPrefix="/ecm/ecap"
and same but with android:scheme="urn:nfc" instead

Comment: @user1 See my updated answer. There's not much else you could do. The NDEF message on that tag was simply not designed with actual applications in mind.

Comment: ah i see, so without switching the URI with the URN (making the URN External type the top most record on the tag) this will be a problem?

Comment: @user1 Correct. I would still expect the intent filter that I added to my answer to work (at least as a quick&dirty fix). I haven't tested that though.

Comment: yes, i can confirm it works. it will have to do for now. thank you for all the help and information. learnt a lot, it helped a lot.